# How to add ghcide into shell.nix

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

I have a Haskell Cabal project. I have been building it using *cabal2nix*. Therefore I have 3 nix files:

- project.nix - The .nix file generated by *cabal2nix*.
- default.nix - Just `haskell.callPackage ./project.nix {}`
- shell.nix - Just returns default's env `(import ./default.nix {}).env`

Recently I decided to set up vscode development environment using [ghcide](https://github.com/haskell/ghcide). In the description it says

> Include `pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcide` in you projects `shell.nix` ...

without further explanation. It sounds like it should be easy job but I don't know how. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In `shell.nix` use the `shellFor` function. It's in the package set rather than `haskell.lib`. Based on the example from the shellFor inline doc on https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix I've renamed `all-packages.nix` added a let binding for it in `shell.nix` and added `ghcide`.

```
    # Returns a derivation whose environment contains a GHC with only
    # the dependencies of packages listed in `packages`, not the
    # packages themselves. Using nix-shell on this derivation will
    # give you an environment suitable for developing the listed
    # packages with an incremental tool like cabal-install.
    # In addition to the "packages" arg and "withHoogle" arg, anything that
    # can be passed into stdenv.mkDerivation can be included in the input attrset
    #
    #     # all-packages.nix
    #     with import <nixpkgs> {};
    #     haskellPackages.extend (haskell.lib.packageSourceOverrides {
    #       frontend = ./frontend;
    #       backend = ./backend;
    #       common = ./common;
    #     })
    #
    #     # shell.nix
    #     let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
    #         allPackages = import ./all-packages.nix;
    #     in
    #     allPackages.shellFor {
    #       packages = p: [p.frontend p.backend p.common];
    #       withHoogle = true;
    #       buildInputs = [ allPackages.ghcide ];
    #     }
    #
    #     -- cabal.project
    #     packages:
    #       frontend/
    #       backend/
    #       common/
    #
    #     bash$ nix-shell --run "cabal new-build all"
    #     bash$ nix-shell --run "python"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ghcide` package to under the `buildTools` config;

```hs
{mkDerivation,stdenv,base,aeson,scotty,wai-extra,text,ghcide}:
mkDerivation {
  pname = "come";
  version = "0.1.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  isLibrary = false;
  isExecutable = true;
  executableHaskellDepends = [
    base aeson scotty wai-extra text
  ];
  buildTools = [ghcide];
  homepage = "http://emre.xyz/come";
  description = "demo project";
  license = with stdenv.lib.licenses; [gpl3Plus];
}
```

Comment: But isn't `project.nix` supposed to be automatically generated therefore manually customizing is not a good idea?